# Is there a way to read a variable from a .ahk file and use it in another batch script file

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey

I dont know of a good way to read another variable in another file

**FileReader.bat**

```
    @echo off

:: Some how read VarX in the ahk file and then save it as another variable

SET VarXReading=%VarX%

echo %VarXReading%

pause
```

**FileToBeRead.ahk**

```
VarX = 69420
```

Comment: This currently looks like an off topic code request. In order to assist you, please provide a fully formatted copy of the actual `.ahk` file content, a full explanation of what you're trying to do, what your actual batch-file code is, and which part of it you believe is not working as it should.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary @Compo, it looks like a valid question as is

Comment: It is necessary @Spyre, for an on topic request for assistance with a fully reproducible issue with the batch file code and the file content. This is a technical site, not a guessing game. Please read [mcve], for a little more information.

Comment: Fair enough, it does feel a bit more like a code request than an issue request. I just took it as a question asking "how do I pass a variable from an ahk script to a batch script".

Comment: We see it differently, @Spyre; I took it to mean, how can my batch file read a line inside a file with a `.ahk` extension, and create a variable using that content, with the data before the `=` as a variable name, and the string data after the `=` as its value string, _(and I'm assuming without including any pre or post whitespace characters)_. Your understanding is to get a AHK script to send something to the batch file, and mine is that the batch file has to read a string within the AHK file, both completely different, and exactly why I've asked for more information.

Comment: I bow to your wisdom @Compo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the variable as a parameter to the batch file. For example

The ahk script:

```
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; Do whatever you need to here
VarX := 69420

Run batch.bat %VarX%
```

The batch script:

```
@echo off
SET VarXReading=%1
echo %VarXReading%
pause
```

Just make sure that the batch script and ahk script are in the same directory for this to work

Comment: For robustness, the batch file should read, 1. `@Echo Off`, 2. `SetLocal EnableExtensions`, 3. `Set "VarXReading=%~1"`,  4. `Echo(%VarXReading%`, and optionally, if it's being invoked using `cmd.exe` with its `/C` option, 5. `Pause`